# How do I make a class that ends with -sm only apply on sm devices?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I want to make the `pagination-sm` class only apply on small devices (sm), but `pagination-sm-sm` doesn't work the way `w-sm-50` for example works, so how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three different ways to achieve this:

1. Use [media-queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to define your own custom class and add the styles manually for the specific screen-sizes

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Example</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <style>
    @media only screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 768px) {
      .pagination {
        --bs-pagination-padding-x: 0.5rem;
        --bs-pagination-padding-y: 0.25rem;
        --bs-pagination-font-size: 0.875rem;
        --bs-pagination-border-radius: 0.25rem;
      }
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

2. Use JavaScript to [toggle classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) based on the current [window-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth).

```js
// Toggle class pagination-sm based on window width
function setPaginationSize() {
  var width = window.innerWidth
  var pagination = document.querySelector('.pagination')
  pagination.classList.toggle("pagination-sm", width >= 576 && width < 768)
}

// Initial call to set pagination size on page load
setPaginationSize()

// Call setPaginationSize() on window resize
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  setPaginationSize()
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Example</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

3. (*This one is quick&dirty, not recommended to use in production.*) Create a duplicate of your pagination and only display it on the screen-sizes where you want to exclude them:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Example</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm d-none d-sm-flex d-md-none">
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pagination d-flex d-sm-none d-md-flex">
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```